# Seamless preloading of media files in html5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a file in which I will have all the media file paths. I want to play those videos in video tag one after the other. But, it should appear like a single video. how to preload those videos one after the other? is this possible in Vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. It is called Media Source Extensions and it is a basis for building MPEG-DASH streaming protocol.

There is one nice project that tries to do what you want without MSE, but it is working rather accidentially, not very stable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any code suggestions? Like How to implement?